# loop remote registry check

Tags: cmd, remote-registry

I am attempting to check if machines in a list have Outlook 2010 standalone installed using a batch file, I can run the script if I hard code each check but I am after something that pulls from a file, this is what I have so far:

**Important Info**:

I am wanting to run this via a batch file, machines can be a mix of windows 7 and XP and it needs to be able to tell the difference between Office 2010 with Outlook and Outlook Standalone

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set INPUT_FILE=%1
set UP_OUTPUT_FILE=yes.txt
set DN_OUTPUT_FILE=no.txt
echo These Machines have Outlook 2010: >> %UP_OUTPUT_FILE%
echo These Machines don't have Outlook 2010: >> %DN_OUTPUT_FILE%

for /f %%i in (%INPUT_FILE%) do (
     reg query \\%%i\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{90140000-001A-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE} > NUL
        if errorlevel 1 goto error1
        if errorlevel 0 goto error0

        :error1
        echo %%i >> %DN_OUTPUT_FILE%
        goto next1

        :error0
        echo %%i >> %UP_OUTPUT_FILE%
        :next1
)
```

The problem I am having is it keeps returning an error:

```
) was unexpected at this time.
```

If I remove the `)` it breaks the script completly and it won't run, if I move it it cuts the loop early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
for /f %%i in (%INPUT_FILE%) do (
    reg query \\%%i\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{90140000-001A-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE} > NUL
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo %%i >> %DN_OUTPUT_FILE%
    ) else (
        echo %%i >> %UP_OUTPUT_FILE%
    )
)
```

Whenever a `goto` command is executed inside a `for` loop, the looping is cancelled.

Comment: Thanks mate, that was amazingly quick, awsome and worth at least 327 internet points! (Had you been quicker you might have got 328)